# How to manage pictures and icons when developing mobile app for both Android and iPhone

Tags: android, ios, swift, xamarin

I'm planning to create a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) mobile app for both iOS and Android devices. (iOS 11 or above / Android 6 or above)
I and my friend used both Java and Swift.
Although we searched about Xamarin or PhoneGap App,
we wanted to use our previous working environment (Xcode/Android Studio) as possible, not spending time on learning new tools.

So we want to work on a BLE app and we want to make it work on both Android and iOS. Currently, we are making the same thing using Swift and Java.

Since the UI part overlaps for both platform, we wish to ask these questions, please.

- If we use Swift and Java separately, we noticed that when a picture is changed, we have to update both to each separate code.
  For example, we wanted to change the round button to a square button shape. Currently, we upload the same picture to the GitHub repository respectively. So we felt something is not efficient and we want to ask is there a better way to change both sides of the app.
  Solutions which require prices, like adding Amazon Web Service S3, is also welcomed.
- We are creating the same UI for both platforms using Swift and Java. Since the UI, button, etc (the interface parts) overlaps for both app, is there a way to code the same UI so both of us don't have to spend time for working the same thing?
  Maybe something like Xamarin could be one way, but I want to hear various advice, please.

Comment: There isn't something as the 'best solution', clearly each technology has its pros and cons which are different by the context. If you are interested in some specific limitations you can ask specific questions, just like this I am 2nd who voted for the question to be closed. It is not allowed to ask for advice on this site but a very specific question that can have exact answer.

Comment: Could you acheve that by xamarin forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just put the images in a common folder in source control that both builds can access it?  That's the common way of doing it.  Using S3 (or any other server) will work if you want to download it at runtime, but since you tried checking it into source control it seems like you want it part of the build.

As for the UI-  native Android and iOS have completely different UIs and ways of working with it.  Really unless you want to go with an html app, you're going to write two different UIs.  The UIs are the least sharable part of a mobile app.  At least for business logic you have a few options (worst case you can always use C, which runs on both).

Comment: Thanks, @Gabe! I didn't know that both have completely different UIs and ways of working with it. About the "business logic you have a few options", can you tell me more about it, please?